# Eevee render much too bright

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Beginner working through Grant Abitt's seashack tutes.

Eevee renders too bright. The colour is ridiculous. Like a nuclear bomb exploding overhead.

I turn down the world strength, I delete lights, I turn the sun down to zero, and it makes no difference. The render is still ridiculously bright.

If anyone can help, here's a link to the blend file.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kaz5jgkt4zl1914/AACu4HlwYoTb8ClGhusl-WEka?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the *Viewport Shading* switch your settings back to default, and in the *Render* settings > *Indirect lighting*, delete the *Lighting Cache*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked perfectly.