# Render view much too bright

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I was following a tutorial from Blender Guru, and in the beginning I had to switch from solid view to render view. But then my viewport was suddenly too bright. I have tried a solution. The link from the solution is here: [Eevee render much too bright](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/189520/115255). But for me that didn't work. Because everything was already set as default. Does anyone else have another solution?

The link of the tuturial from Blender Guru: https://youtu.be/ZTxBrjN1ugA

Image of my problem:
[image: The problem]

Comment: what color is your world color set to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ethan mentioned in his comment, the immediate suspicion in a case like this is that your World Shader is too bright. If you want the background to be as bright as it is without "washing out your mesh", you can separate the background "look" and the background "lighting" by combining two different backgrounds with a Mix Shader, using the *Is Camera Ray* output of a *Light Path* Node as a Mix Factor:

[image: Shading]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! My problem is now solved! I have followed your steps that you have told. And the image was very helpful too. Thank you!